# Block serialization of database writes

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Is there a more elegant and reusable/general way to do the following.
I am writing this a lot, essentially on every write job as my data balloons to 100s of 1000s then 1,000,000s of records on table after table.

```
    .then(function(nodes){
            var job=Promise.resolve()
            var blocks=[]
            while (nodes.length){
                    blocks.push(nodes.splice(0,NODES_BLOCK_SIZE))
            }
            _.each(blocks,function(block){
                    job=job.then(function(){
                            return Node.bulkCreate(block)
                    })
            })
            return job
    })
```

I am about to factor that so I can pass `Node.bulkCreate` and `NODES_BLOCK_SIZE`to,

```
function block_op(data,func,blocksize){
    var job=Promise.resolve()
    var blocks=[]
    while (data.length){
        blocks.push(data.splice(0,blocksize))
    }
    _.each(blocks,function(block){
        job=job.then(function(){
            return func(block)
        })
      })
     return job
  }
```

but it still feels like 10 lines of code too much.

My real problems are not so much MySQL complaining when Sequelize fires over 64 megs at it, its the input, I cant read an arbitrarily large table into store, and thats harder than just reusing that block of code above.
I have sketched this piece of code UNTESTED,which reads blocks from one table, resolves the foreign keys in the target table and deletes the primary key, and writes. its not too bad and maybe this is the answer,but I it feels like way too common a pattern not to be better supported..

```
import events from "events"
test()
.then(function(){
    console.log("DONE")
})

function test(){
    blockster= new Blockster({
        read:stop_times.findAll,
        write:StopTimes.bulkCreate,
        transform:transform,
        block_size:1024*32,
        clause:{
            where:{
// read the whole table
//                trip_id:trip_id
            }
        },
        params:{
            DataSetId:DataSetId
        }
    }) 
    return blockster.promise
}

function transform(block){
    // resolve foreign keys on the target table
    var stop_ids=block.map(function(record){
        return record.stop_id
    })
    .filter(uniq)
    var trip_id=block.map(function(record){
        return record.trip_id
    })
    .filter(uniq)

    var StopId=[]
    var TripId=[]

    return Trips.findAll({
        where:{
            trip_id:{
                $in:trip_id
            },
            DataSetId:self.options.params.DataSetId
        }
    })
    .then(function(trips){
        trips.forEach((trip)=>{
            TripId[trip.source_id]=trip.id
        })
        return Stops.findAll({
            where:{
                stop_id:{
                    $in:stop_ids
                },
                DataSetId:self.options.params.DataSetId
            }
        })
    })
    .then(function(stops){
        stops.forEach((stop)=>{
            StopId[stop.source_id]=stop.id
        })

        block.forEach(function(record){
            record.source_id=record.id
            delete record.id
            record.StopId=StopId[record.stop_id]
            record.TripId=TripId[record.trip_id]
        })
    })
}

class Blockster extends events {
    constructor(options){
        super()
        var self=this
        this.options=options
        this.promise=new Promise(function(resolve,error){
            self.resolve=resolve
            self.error=error
        })
        this.block_number=0
        this.on('block',this.output)
        this.on('clear',this.input)
        this.on('end',this.resolve)
        this.trigger('clear')
        return this
    }

    input(){
        var self=this
        self.options.read(self.options.clause.extend(self.clause()))
        .then(function(block){
             if (!block)
                return self.trigger('end')
            self.block_number++
            self.trigger('block',block)
        })
    }

    output(block){
        var self=this
        self.options.transform(block)
        .then(function(block){
            return self.options.write(block)
        })
        .then(function(){
            self.trigger('clear') 
        })
    }   

    clause(){
        return {
            offset:this.block_number*this.options.block_size,
          limit:this.options.block_size
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: is there a cleaner way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this.

```
const events =require( "events")
const spliceop =require( "./spliceop")
const _=require("underscore")
const sleep=require("sleep-promise")
const DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE_OUTPUT =1024*64
const DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE_INPUT =1024*65

class Blockster extends events {
    constructor(options){
        super()
        var self=this
        this.block_number=0
        this.options=options || {}
        this.options.block_size_input=this.options.block_size_input || DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE_INPUT
        this.options.block_size_transform=this.options.block_size_transform || DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE_INPUT
        this.options.block_size_output=this.options.block_size_output || DEFAULT_BLOCK_SIZE_OUTPUT
        this.promise=new Promise(function(resolve,error){
            self.resolve=resolve
            self.error=error
        })
        this.on('read',output.bind(this))
        this.on('clear',input.bind(this))
        this.on('end',this.resolve)
        return this
    }

    run(){
        this.emit('clear')
        return this.promise
    }

    input(){
        var self=this
        return self.options.read(_.extend(self.options.clause,self.clause()))
        .then(function(buffer){
             if (!buffer || !buffer.length)
                return self.emit('end')
            self.block_number++
            self.emit('read',buffer)
        })
    }

    output(buffer){
        var self=this
        return spliceop(buffer, self.options.transform,self.options.block_size_transform  )
        .then(function(buffer){
            if (self.options.write)
                return spliceop(buffer,self.options.write, self.options.block_size_output )
        })
        .then(()=>{
            if (self.options.sleeper)
                return sleep(self.options.sleeper)
        })
        .then(function(){
            if (self.options.read_once)
                self.emit('end') 
            else
                self.emit('clear') 
        })
    }   

    clause(){
        return {
            offset:this.block_number*this.options.block_size_input,
            limit:this.options.block_size_input
        }
    }
}

function output(block){
    return this.output(block)
}

function input(){
    return this.input()
}

module.exports=Blockster
```

I do things like this with it. I have 10 of these phases, all involving potentially memory busting input streams. harnessing them all in this publication model has been very effective but I stil feel that I should be leveraging something other than events and promises.

```
class Normalizer {
    Normalizer(){
        var barg={

            read:this.sequelize.models.Stop.findAll.bind(this.sequelize.models.Stop),
            write:resolve_writer.bind(this),
            transform:resolve_transform.bind(this),
            clause:{
                where:{
                    $or:[
                        {
                            normalized:null
                        },
                        {
                            normalized:0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            block_size_input:OVERPASS_BLOCK_SIZE
        }
        if (this.options.source)
            barg.clause.where.DataSetId=this.DataSetId

        var blockster= new Blockster(barg)
        return blockster.run()
    }
}
function resolve_transform(block){
   // do stuff
   return block // or other array of stuff for wtrite to handle
}
function resolve_write(block){
   // usually update stuff, if just blockCreate we can pass that to blockster
}
```